# Wrong number or types of arguments - Oracle Error in .NET application

Tags: .net, oracle, arguments

I am calling a procedure from .Net and I keep getting an error that says, "wrong number or types of arguments in call to initiate_user_priv_app.  I've compared the parameters, the types, and I don't see where the disconnect is.  I have the same number of parameters, same order, same type of variables.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
 Procedure Initate_User_Priv_App
(
P_Cred_Provider_Id         In Cred_Provider.Cred_Provider_Id%Type,
P_Cred_Assignment_Id       In Cred_Assignment.Cred_Assignment_Id%Type,
P_Priv_Application_Mtf_Id  In Priv_Application.Priv_Application_Mtf_Id%Type,
P_Priv_Application_Type_Id In Priv_Application.Priv_Application_Type_Id%Type,
P_Person_Email_Txt         In Sys_Person_Email.Person_Email_Txt%Type,
P_Communication_Type_Id    In Sys_Person_Communication.Communication_Type_Id%Type,
P_Person_Communication_Txt In Sys_Person_Communication.Person_Communication_Txt%Type,
P_Audit_User_Id            In Sys_User.User_Id%Type,
P_Audit_User_Mtf_Id        In Mtf.Mtf_Id%Type,
P_Audit_Predecessor_Id     In Priv_Application.Audit_Predecessor_Id%Type,
P_Priv_Application_Id      Out Priv_Application.Priv_Application_Id%Type,
P_Result                   Out Varchar2,
P_Return_Code              Out Number


using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(this.connString))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sql_privileging_functions.initate_user_priv_app";

            #region Parameterization
            OracleParameter outputApplicationId = new OracleParameter("p_priv_application_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, 18, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
            OracleParameter outputResult = new OracleParameter("p_result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
            OracleParameter outputResultCode = new OracleParameter("p_return_code", OracleDbType.Decimal, 18, null, ParameterDirection.Output);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_cred_provider_id", credAssignment.CredProviderId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_cred_assignment_id", credAssignment.CredAssignmentId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_priv_application_mtf_id", credAssignment.AssignmentMtf));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_priv_application_type_id", credAssignment.PrivApplicationTypeId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_person_email_txt", credAssignment.Email));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_communication_type_id", credAssignment.PhoneTypeId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_person_communication_txt", credAssignment.Phone));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_audit_user_id", credAssignment.AuditUserId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_audit_user_mtf_id", credAssignment.AuditUserMTFId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_audit_user_predecessor_id", credAssignment.AuditUserId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_priv_application_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_return_code", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(outputApplicationId);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(outputResult);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(outputResultCode);

            #endregion Parameterization

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteReader();

            applicationId = outputApplicationId.Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (long)(OracleDecimal)outputApplicationId.Value;
            result = outputResult.Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : (string)(OracleString)outputResult.Value;
            resultCode = outputResultCode.Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (long)(OracleDecimal)outputResultCode.Value;

            credAssignment.PrivApplicationId = applicationId;
            credAssignment.Result = result;
            credAssignment.ReturnCode = resultCode;
        }
```

Comment: It does, but i need those output parameters to populate the three variables applicationId, result, and resultCode.  Is there another way?

Comment: If I do that, I get a 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleNullValueException' error when the debug point hits  applicationId = outputApplicationId.Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (long)(OracleDecimal)outputApplicationId.Value;

Comment: Could you write your answer in the "Answer" section so that I can mark it as the correct answer?  Your answer helped me reach a resolution and it saved me a lot of headache and time wasted.  Had it not been for you i wouldn't have realized that I had my output parameters written out twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code is redundant and the cause of the wrong number of arguments exception you're receiving:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_priv_application_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_return_code", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output));
```

as your output parameters are added immediately after them:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(outputApplicationId);
cmd.Parameters.Add(outputResult);
cmd.Parameters.Add(outputResultCode);
```

Additionally, you could cast `outputApplicationId` to `OracleDecimal` and use its `IsNull` property for the assignment, as currently you'll get an `OracleNullValueException` when trying to access the `null` value (see [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2321436)):

> OracleDecimal and OracleString (and some other types like OracleDate, etc.) have an "IsNull" property you can use if you cast the Value property to its runtime type...
>
> if ((OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["p1"].Value).IsNull) { …do something… } 
>   else { …do something else… }
>
> Or maybe something like this...
>   Decimal p1val = ((OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["p1"].Value).IsNull ? 0 : ((OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["AVG_SALARY"].Value).Value;